# Code efficiency with LibGDX Box2D Player Movement

Tags: java, libgdx

I am using Box2D in LibGDX to move my player around. The world gravity is set on (0f,0f). However, my code feels long and blunt and I feel like I could refactor it to implement it more efficient, but I'm not sure how. Is there anything I can improve?

```
private void playerMovement() {
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.W)){
        body.setLinearVelocity(new Vector2(0f,30f));
    }if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.S)){
        body.setLinearVelocity(new Vector2(0f, -30f));
    }if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.A)){
        body.setLinearVelocity(new Vector2(-30f, 0f));
    }if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.D)){
        body.setLinearVelocity(new Vector2(30f,0f));
    }if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.W) && Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.A)){
        body.setLinearVelocity(new Vector2(-30f, 30f));
    }if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.W) && Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.D)){
        body.setLinearVelocity(new Vector2(30f, 30f));
    }if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.S) && Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.A)){
        body.setLinearVelocity(new Vector2(-30f, -30f));
    }if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.S) && Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.D)){
        body.setLinearVelocity(new Vector2(30f, -30f));
    }else if(!Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.ANY_KEY)){
        body.setLinearVelocity(new Vector2(0f,0f));
    }
}
```

Is this method good for smooth movement using Box2D? The world gravity is set on (0f,0f). Not sure if i can do it writing less code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More efficient way.

```
static float speed = 30; // move speed outside method to not create it each frame.

private void playerMovement() {
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.W)){
        body.setLinearVelocity(0f, speed); // removed Vector2(), it's not a good idea to cteate it each frame.
    }if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.S)){
        body.setLinearVelocity(0f, -speed);
    }if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.A)){
        body.setLinearVelocity(-speed, 0f);
    }if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.D)){
        body.setLinearVelocity(speed,0f);
    }if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.W) && Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.A)){
        body.setLinearVelocity(-speed, speed);
    }if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.W) && Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.D)){
        body.setLinearVelocity(speed, speed);
    }if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.S) && Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.A)){
        body.setLinearVelocity(-speed, -speed);
    }if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.S) && Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.D)){
        body.setLinearVelocity(speed, -speed);
    }else {
        body.setLinearVelocity(0f,0f);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Final code of PlayerMovement if anyone want to use it. I had to modify the answer's code to work because of some mistakes but now it works correctly.

```
private void playerMovement() {
    float speed = 30f;
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.W) || Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.UP)) {
        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.A) || Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.LEFT)) {
            body.setLinearVelocity(-speed,speed);
        }else if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.D) || Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.RIGHT)) {
            body.setLinearVelocity(speed, speed);
        }else
            body.setLinearVelocity(0f, speed);
    }else if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.S) || Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.DOWN)) {
        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.A) || Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.LEFT)) {
            body.setLinearVelocity(-speed, -speed);
        }else if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.D) || Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.RIGHT)) {
            body.setLinearVelocity(speed, -speed);
        }else
            body.setLinearVelocity(0f, -speed);
    }else if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.A) || Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.LEFT)) {
        body.setLinearVelocity(-speed, 0f);
    }else if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.D) || Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.RIGHT)) {
        body.setLinearVelocity(speed, 0f);
    }else
        body.setLinearVelocity(0f, 0f);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for new answer with explaination but i will stay with current code because  i'm also using LEFT, RIGHT... keys and it will need more code. Also thanks for reminder about variable.